# Reactjs fetch method returns empty array

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to fetch some data, which is in the form:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "some_data": "..."
  },
  ...
]
```

What I am trying to get is a list displaying the items from the fetch. If I put the same data in a file within the project, it works.

However when I tried to map it, I got an error saying "`this.data.map` is not a function". So I changed it a bit by using `Array.from()`. It currently looks like this:

```
export default class Main extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items = [];
    };
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }

  getData = () => {
    fetch("URL",{
      method: "get",
      header: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
    .then(response => {
      var array = Array.from(response.json())
      this.setState({items: array});
    })
  }

  render() {
    const list = this.state.items.map((r, i) => {
      return (
        <Item
          id = { r[i].id }
          some_data = { r[i].some_data }
          ...
        />
      )
    })
    return(
      <div>
        <Item
          p = {list}
        >
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It may be that your data isn't at the 'root' of response from the service.  Try console.log(response) to see what is in response and look for the node containing your data.  It's could be your data is in response.data, try a console.log on that.  Typically, response objects from a service contain a lot more than just the data....

Comment: @ChrisAdams if I console log the response I get:

>Promise {<resolved>: Array(15)}

When expanded I see the data that I want to be displaying.

Comment: Get what?  Nothing?

Comment: where are you calling the method `getData()` you usually call it in `componentDidMount`

Comment: I added a method `componentDidMount` where I call `getData()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all no state is neede to store the response. Its happening due to the state value is not reflecting in your render.

1. Call a function inside success response & map the response inside the function & set State there.

OR

2. Put the below code outside render function assigning to variable like below

   const list = this.state.items.map((r, i) => {
             return (
               
         )
       })
       return(
         
           
         
       )
     }

   render () {
     {list}
   }

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.....

It's better to load the data once component is mounted.  Also, there's no URL, I'm assuming that you've hidden this.

Once you 'see' what's in response, you can code against that accordingly.

```
export default class Main extends React.Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          items = [];
        };
        // this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){

        // Attempt to load data once component mounted.

        this.getData();

    }

    getData = () => {
        // Don't you need the URL below, or have you deliberately hidden it?
        fetch("URL",{
        method: "get",
        header: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
    .then(response => {

        console.log(response);  // See exactly what is in response....

        var array = Array.from(response.json())
        console.log(array);  // Check array is really what you want

        // You could try a JSON.Parse....
        var jsonArray = JSON.Parse(response);
        console.log(jsonArray);

        this.setState({items: array});
     })
  }

  render() {
      const list = this.state.items.map((r, i) => {
      return (
          <Item
          id = { r[i].id }
          some_data = { r[i].some_data }
           ...
        />
       )
    })
    return(
      <div>
       <Item
          p = {list}
        >
     </div>
    )
   }
}
```

Comment: The `console.log(response)` returns some info on the object. If I put a `console.log(this.state.items)` then it returns an empty array.

Comment: You mean that response contains the data you want? Can you share the response?  Also, you don't say exactly where you put thie'console.log(this.state.items)' line.  If it's immediately after the setState call, then state may not have been competed before the console.log command.

Comment: You might want make sure you've parsed the response properly too.  See code example for amendments

Comment: just be aware of`setState`  - State Updates May Be Asynchronous
 - https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: Agreed.  Inferred that above.